# Finding expectation where the density has an indicator function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Let $f(z_1, z_2) = g(z_1)1(z_2=0)$.

What is the expectation of $E(Z_1^2)$? Is it zero? I think it depends on $g(z_1)$. Am I correct?

Comment: $f(z_1,z_2)=g(z_1)\mathbb{1}_{z_2=0}=f(z_1,0)$

Comment: @MajaBlumenstein I am not getting what you are trying to point out here?

Comment: Yes, it depends on $g(z_1)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for confirming.